# Swift: How do I pass in a value for this argument?

Tags: swift, function, syntax, arguments

```
rk4_func(
    y_array: [Double],
    f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)],
    t_val: Double,
    h_val: Double)
    -> [Double]
```

I don't understand how to use the argument `f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)]`. How exactly do I pass that in when calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of tricky :)

A quick remainder about [Swift's *function types*:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174) a type of `(Int) -> Float` means: a function that takes an int and returns a float. Okay, now back to your question:

As the argument `f_array` says (or, at least, tries to), it expects an *array of functions.* Inside this array, each function then accepts *two* arguments:

- a doubles array: `[Double]`
- a single double: `Double`

and returns a `Double`.

A quick example to get you going:

```
func f(_ a: [Double], _ b: Double) -> Double { ... }
func g(_ a: [Double], _ b: Double) -> Double { ... }

let f_array = [f, g]
```

---

There's a fair share of Swift magic up there. Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: @ScottThompson Sorry for overriding your suggestions man... SO folks move fast these days, haha :-)

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for contributing!